# Mac os Catalina(10.15.7) not able to open gitk

Tags: git, macos, operating-system, gitk

I have installed git and git-gui with the following commands:

> brew install git

> brew install git-gui

> git config --global --add alias.gui '!sh -c '/usr/local/opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui''

Now when I run `gitk` I am getting some error that I am not able fix:

> objc[74842]: autorelease pool page 0x7fa2240a4000 corrupted
> magic     0x71fbbca0 0x00007fff 0xb6d20633 0x00000000
> should be 0xa1a1a1a1 0x4f545541 0x454c4552 0x21455341
> pthread   0x0
> should be 0x111da9dc0
> Abort trap: 6

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: gitk is built on tcl/tk and wish (a "shell" for running tcl/tk programs). This kind of crash means someone's build a buggy version of wish, perhaps by mixing and matching the wrong libraries. I don't know what you'll need to do to fix it though.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this question: [gitk error: autorelease pool page corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938739/gitk-error-autorelease-pool-page-corrupted).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by install upgrades and then installing `tcl`.

```
brew install tcl
```

Comment: Actually, if I call git-gui it does work, though gitk still does not.

Comment: `git-gui` and `gitk` are two entirely different applications.  `gitk` still crashes after installing tcl.  To circumvent the crash, edit `~/.config/git/gitk` to change `set geometry(state) zoomed` back to `set geometry(state) normal`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938739/gitk-error-autorelease-pool-page-corrupted).